# Xcode 5.1 - Button Disable/Enable not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

App with 4 buttons - just want to control their behavior - i.e. push a button and it is disabled while others are enabled.

From other questions/answers here, I've created the following .h entries:

```
@interface TestButtonsViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)b1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)b2:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)b3:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)b4:(id)sender;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *b1;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *b2;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *b3;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *b4;
```

and the .m

```
- (IBAction)b1:(id)sender {

UIButton *b1 = (UIButton *) sender;
b1.enabled = NO;
UIButton *b2 = (UIButton *) sender;
b2.enabled = YES;
UIButton *b3 = (UIButton *) sender;
b3.enabled = NO;
UIButton *b4 = (UIButton *) sender;
b4.enabled = NO;
}

- (IBAction)b2:(id)sender {

UIButton *b1 = (UIButton *) sender;
b1.enabled = NO;
UIButton *b2 = (UIButton *) sender;
b2.enabled = NO;
UIButton *b3 = (UIButton *) sender;
b3.enabled = YES;
UIButton *b4 = (UIButton *) sender;
b4.enabled = NO;
}

- (IBAction)b3:(id)sender {

UIButton *b1 = (UIButton *) sender;
b1.enabled = NO;
UIButton *b2 = (UIButton *) sender;
b2.enabled = NO;
UIButton *b3 = (UIButton *) sender;
b3.enabled = NO;
UIButton *b4 = (UIButton *) sender;
b4.enabled = YES;
}

- (IBAction)b4:(id)sender {

UIButton *b1 = (UIButton *) sender;
b1.enabled = YES;
UIButton *b2 = (UIButton *) sender;
b2.enabled = YES;
UIButton *b3 = (UIButton *) sender;
b3.enabled = YES;
UIButton *b4 = (UIButton *) sender;
b4.enabled = NO;
}
```

When I save, build, run and push the buttons starting at 1 and going down the buttons 1 and 2 do disable after I push them; but when I press 3 it doesn't; furthermore when I press 4 it doesn't enable 1 and 2.

Comment: Why are you creating multiple variables that refer to `sender`?! In your code, buttons b1, b2, b3 and b4 are the same. You are just creating a new pointer to the same object...

Comment: when you add the TouchUp action (Ctrl + button) - 'sender' is what it creates in the .h file - for ALL buttons...

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect behavior for what you want to do, you can't cast multiple buttons from the same sender and expect them to behave properly. Use your properties you already have instead and try this:

```
- (IBAction)b1:(id)sender 
{
    self.b1.enabled = NO;
    self.b2.enabled = YES;
    self.b3.enabled = NO;
    self.b4.enabled = NO;
}

- (IBAction)b2:(id)sender 
{
    self.b1.enabled = NO;
    self.b2.enabled = NO;
    self.b3.enabled = YES;
    self.b4.enabled = NO;
}

- (IBAction)b3:(id)sender 
{
    self.b1.enabled = NO;
    self.b2.enabled = NO;
    self.b3.enabled = NO;
    self.b4.enabled = YES;
}

- (IBAction)b4:(id)sender 
{
    self.b1.enabled = YES;
    self.b2.enabled = YES;
    self.b3.enabled = YES;
    self.b4.enabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is Button.**userInteractionEnabled** = NO

Comment: This disabled buttons; but setting to YES didn't re-enable them.